# Calling function when use authentication in laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

I using authentication default controller for register users . I want to call function  for save some extra data on an other database when register comleted.
How can i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/**
 * Handle a registration request for the application.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function postRegister(Request $request)
{
    $validator = $this->validator($request->all());

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        $this->throwValidationException(
            $request, $validator
        );
    }

    // Your custom code

    Auth::login($this->create($request->all()));

    return redirect($this->redirectPath());
}
```

This is the function that handles registration. You can write it again along side your custom code in `AuthController`